# Surround a GUID with single quotes in C# using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, guid

GUIDs may appear in a statement with or without single quotes, *e.g.*

```
string inputString = @"ObjectID='{A591C480-2979-48ED-9796-5C3149472E7A}' and ObjectID={90f0fb85-0f80-4466-9b8c-2025949e2079}";
```

My requirement is:

> If a GUID is surrounded by single quotes, skip it.
>   If it is not surrounded by single quotes, then surround it with single quotes.

I am expecting output to be like

```
inputString = @"ObjectID='{A591C480-2979-48ED-9796-5C3149472E7A}' and ObjectID='{90f0fb85-0f80-4466-9b8c-2025949e2079}'"
```

or

```
inputString = @"ObjectID='{A591C480-2979-48ED-9796-5C3149472E7A}' and ObjectID={'90f0fb85-0f80-4466-9b8c-2025949e2079'}"
```

Regex to find a GUID inside single quotes is

```
var quotedGuidMatches = Regex.Matches(inputString, @"'[({]?\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\s?[-]?\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?[-]?\s?){3}\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}\s?[})]?'");
```

Regex to find GUID is

```
var guidMatches = Regex.Matches(inputString, @"\b[({]?\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\s?[-]?\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?[-]?\s?){3}\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}\s?[})]?\b");
```

Regex to surround a guid with single quotes is

```
inputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"\b[({]?\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\s?[-]?\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?[-]?\s?){3}\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}\s?[})]?\b", "'$0'", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Unfortunately this one finds all GUIDs inside the single quotes and without single quotes. The replace method will end up surrounding guid already having single quotes with multiple single quotes.
Could you please help me find the GUIDs which are not inside single quotes only. And then surround it with single quotes.

Comment: It is not very clear why you want to use Regex for this. What's the problem checking the first and last character of the input string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match a GUID inside single quotes and capture it to be able to test this group for a match inside a match evaluator, and match a GUID in all other contexts that will be enclosed with single quotes:

```
var inputString = @"ObjectID='{A591C480-2979-48ED-9796-5C3149472E7A}' and ObjectID={90f0fb85-0f80-4466-9b8c-2025949e2079}";
var guid = @"[({]?\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\s?[-]?\s?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?[-]?\s?){3}\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}\s?[})]?";
inputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, $@"('{guid}')|{guid}", x =>
    x.Groups[1].Success ? x.Value : $"'{x.Value}'");
Console.WriteLine(inputString);
// => ObjectID='{A591C480-2979-48ED-9796-5C3149472E7A}' and ObjectID='{90f0fb85-0f80-4466-9b8c-2025949e2079}'
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/neuHyT).

Note I made the `([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?[-]?\s?)` capturing group in the original pattern non-capturing, `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?[-]?\s?)`.

The `$@"('{guid}')|{guid}"` string literal creates a regex like

```
('[({]?\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\s?[-]?\s?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?[-]?\s?){3}\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}\s?[})]?')|[({]?\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\s?[-]?\s?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?[-]?\s?){3}\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}\s?[})]?
```

The first alternative matches and captures a GUID inside single quotes into Group 1 and the second alternative matches GUIDs in other contexts.  The `x => x.Groups[1].Success ? x.Value : $"'{x.Value}'"` line only wraps the match with `'`s if it was not already enclosed with single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If Regex is not required, why not just use a simple approach?

```
void Main()
{
    string ObjectID="'{A591C480-2979-48ED-9796-5C3149472E7A}'";

    if (!(ObjectID.StartsWith("'") && ObjectID.EndsWith("'")))
    {
        ObjectID = $"'{ObjectID.Trim('\'')}'";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(ObjectID);
}
```

I added the call to `Trim` in case the string only had a single apostrophe at the beginning or end.

Comment: I read the problem as the guid(s) is embedded in a longer string like "ObjectID='{A591C480-2979-48ED-9796-5C3149472E7A}' and ObjectID={90f0fb85-0f80-4466-9b8c-2025949e2079}"

Comment: @AdamG - Yes I see that.  That does seem to be the requirement.  I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with this solution. The idea is to remove quotes from the Guids that have quotes. Then add quotes to all the (naked) Guids.  If there is any other solution which can find exact Guid ***without*** single quotes and surround it with single quotes using pure Regex, I would accept that as answer.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegexTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string inputString = @"ObjectID = '{A591C480-2979-48ED-9796-5C3149472E7A}' and ObjectID = { 90f0fb85 - 0f80 - 4466 - 9b8c - 2025949e2079 }";
            Console.WriteLine("Before: ");
            Console.WriteLine(inputString);

            var quotedGuidMatches = Regex.Matches(inputString, @"'[({]?\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\s?[-]?\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?[-]?\s?){3}\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}\s?[})]?'");

            var guidMatches = Regex.Matches(inputString, @"\b[({]?\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\s?[-]?\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?[-]?\s?){3}\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}\s?[})]?\b");

            //First eliminate single quotes from guoted guids
            foreach(var quotedGuid in quotedGuidMatches)
            {
                inputString = inputString.Replace(quotedGuid.ToString(), quotedGuid.ToString().Trim('\''));
            }            

            //After single quotes have been eliminated from guids, surround all naked guids with single quotes
            inputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"\b[({]?\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\s?[-]?\s?([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s?[-]?\s?){3}\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}\s?[})]?\b", "'$0'", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            Console.WriteLine("\nAfter: ");
            Console.WriteLine(inputString);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]